# Extending RAID 1 partition

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I am trying to extend my current RAID 1 partition in Ubuntu. Although I've found bunch of manuals for it, I am not sure I understand everything.

1) I had HP server with 2 SSD, which were created in RAID 1 using HP Smart Array utility.

2) I installed Ubuntu Server with default partitioning during installation. This created the following:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda      8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 915.1G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

3) Now I installed 4 new SSDs and used again HP Smart Array utility to extend RAID 1 and logical device, so it is seen as one RAID 1 with 6 devices.

4) Now Ubuntu sees increased volume, but partitioned with the old configuration:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000512503808 bytes, 5860375984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 32768 bytes / 98304 bytes    
Disklabel type: gpt    
Disk identifier: F99AC671-0D8F-400E-99D6-96FC1B69664F    
Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type    
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System    
/dev/sda2     1050624 1920172031 1919121408 915.1G Linux filesystem    
/dev/sda3  1920172032 1953458175   33286144  15.9G Linux swap
```

5) Ideally, I want to increase the size of `/dev/sda2` partition being able to save current data. So my first question is: **in order to extend `/dev/sda2` should I remove `/dev/sda3` with SWAP?**

6) I found that the best option is `mdadm` utility, though it says that:

```
sudo mdadm -D /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sda does not appear to be an md device
```

and

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>
```

**Does that mean that I should have setup mdadm initially when I just installed Ubuntu, and it cannot be used now correctly?**

And **what is the correct sequence of steps in this situation to extend the partition `/dev/sda2` and make it all in one RAID?**

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `mdadm` is useless in your case -- Linux sees a regular disk device, not a RAID array. (`sda` is not a RAID device as far as Linux is concerned.) Yes, to extend `sda2` you need to delete `sda3` first. Delete swap entry from `/etc/fstab`. Boot from the installation medium in a live session. Use `swapoff -a` to turn off swap, then delete `sda3`, then extend `sda2`, then extend the filesystem if needed, then re-create `sda3`. Reboot into the installed system, `mkswap` on `sda3`, update `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexP . The RAID is installed on hardware level. When you say  "Linux sees a regular disk device, not a RAID array", this means that no mirroring data actually happens and it is just wasting half of the space? If so, should I redo partitioning of the system to make it as RAID 1? Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with the specific computer model, so I cannot say for sure, but, since you mentioned HP Smart Array, I would expect the hardware RAID controller to do the mirroring. What is certain is that the operating system does not see a software RAID device (`/dev/md*`), and I would have been surprised if it did -- the hardware RAID has no reason to propagate array structure to the OS.

Comment: @AlexP you are right. I have googled around and check manually (pulled out SSD to see if OS still boots). So apparently I can make a partition extension as it would be for regular storage, as you described. Thank you for your help.